# How can I access the attributes of an object I passed through intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I declared a class of the type Schedule.
I have an instance called schedule and I pass it through intent to the CalculatedSchedule Activity

> startActivity(Intent(this,CalculatedSchedule::class.java).apply {
>                   putExtra(SCHEDULE,schedule)
>               })

How do I access the values on the CalculatedSchedule Activity?

I stored it on the variable schedule

> val schedule = intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.SCHEDULE)

But then I can't access the attributes.
I tried casting the result from getSerializableExtra but it tells me the classifier Schedule doesn't have a companion object. 
I searched companion objects I don't see why it matters in my case.
I also checked what's being returned from getSerializableExtra in debug and it's a Schedule object.

Answer (score 1):

```
val schedule: CalculatedSchedule = intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.SCHEDULE)
```

or

```
val schedule = intent.getSerializableExtra<CalculatedSchedule>(MainActivity.SCHEDULE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
The class is Schedule and CalculatedSchedule is the Activity.
I tried the first option and I get type mismatch saying it found Serializable and it required Schedule.
The second option I get "No type arguments expected for fun getSerializableExtra(name: String!): Serializable!"

Comment: You must inherit  Serializable interface in these classes.

Comment: I forgot to add that I already do `class Schedule(var days:Array<ScheduledDay>):Serializable{`

Comment: Did you import right `Schedule` class? Android has class with that name too :)

Comment: The class is in the same package. And the link leads to the right class.